# How to place 'Background Image over another div'?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

This question maybe not cool  but want to know proper way to solve this task. Of course using HTML,CSS,Bootstrap.
[Something like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmuLS.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `CSS transform`:

```css
.cover {
  background: blue;
  height: 100px
}

.block {
  transform: translate(0, -65px);
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.text {
  background: red;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cover"></div>
<div class="block">
    <div class="text">Hello, "Background Image over another div"</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick example, use negative margin top to place section over other section, replace styles with background image if you wish.

```
   <section style="background:red;width:100%;height:300px">
   </section>
   <section style="width:100%;margin-top:-150px">
        <div class="container">
              <div style="width:100%;height:300px; background: white;"></div>
         </div>
   </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KevYXE

Basically I created a DIV overlay and a background DIV. The background DIV is split into two sections. The top section uses a background image and the bottom section is a solid color. I used a relative position for the overlay and used percentages to make sure everything stays center.

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="bg-overlay"></div>
  <div id="bg-wrap">
    <div id="bg-top"></div>
    <div id="bg-bottom"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  background: #ccc;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#bg-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  height: 70%;
  max-width: 800px;
  width: 80%;
  top: 15%;
  background: #fff;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 6px -6px #666;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 6px 6px -6px #666;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 6px -6px #666;
}

#bg-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#bg-top {
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  background: url("https://picsum.photos/2200/300") no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}

#bg-bottom {
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  background: #cccccc; 
}
```

Comment: Wow ! Thanks Brother :)